# How to secret authenticate my app without ask anything to the user

Tags: ios, objective-c, oauth-2.0, google-drive-api

I'm trying to make an iOS app. I want to list files of MY google drive in the app. But at the moment the user have to log himself with MY google account to work with the files I want.

How can I authenticate my app with my google account to list files I want without ask any account to the user ?
I tried to work with this URL but it still ask account to the user :

`https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly&client_id=846173053406-qr0eh9j32rle71u7u5si5pd0kpfesuap.apps.googleusercontent.com&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http://localhost&access_type=offline&approval_prompt=force`

I'm not sure to understand how secret authenticate works.

Thanks you !

Answer (score 0):

I never used the google drive sdk but typically the way you persist data such as login information is either using [NSUserDefault](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/nsuserdefaults_class/reference/reference.html) or by using the [keychain](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/01introduction/introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000897)